# LuaLaTeX with siunitx, luainputenc and T1 fontenc produces an error

Tags: luatex, siunitx, font-encodings, input-encodings, minionpro

### Error

I get the following error when compiling the MWE below with LuaLaTeX:

```
ERROR: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].

--- TeX said ---
\curr@fontshape ->\f@encoding 
                              /\f@family /\f@series /\f@shape 
l.6780 ... \__siunitx_unit_non_latin:n { "00B0 } C }
```

The problem occurs in the file `siunitx.sty` on the following line:

```
\siunitx_declare_unit:Nx \degreeCelsius { \__siunitx_unit_non_latin:n { "00B0 } C }
```

### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}%[=v2]

\begin{document}

«\SI{40}{\celsius}»

\end{document}
```

### Background Info

As written in the siuntix documentation, siunitx assumes `TU` font encoding when compiling with LuaLaTeX. But this is no option for me, as I rely on the `MinionPro` package (that needs `T1`) and I want to be able to compile my documents with pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. I need LuaLaTeX because of the `graphdrawing.trees` library of TikZ.

When I use the compatibility flag `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]` it gives me no error. But I would like to use the current version of siunitx.

### Question

Can this bug be solved or is there a workaround?

Comment: why do you use luainputenc?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer because I want to compile the document using pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Is there a better option?

Comment: really you should avoid luainputenc as it disables all unicode handling it will be incompatible with most uses of luatex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there an alternative that I can use with the MinionPro package? I want to compile the same source using PdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without luainputenc it works. But you need then to define non-ascii chars:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}%[=v2]
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{«}{\guillemetleft}
\newunicodechar{»}{\guillemetright}
\begin{document}

«\SI{40}{\celsius}» 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Unicode engines, `siunitx` hasn't to-date expected any characters which are used as symbols to be active characters. As some of the assumptions here are during the loading routine, a 'simple' patch is not really viable.

I will be releasing v3.1.7 of `siunitx` shortly: this adds additional defensive code for the case where UTF-8 characters are active in Unicode engines.